# Как назначить горячие клавиши в консоли?

Tags: linux, bash, hotkeys, shortcuts

Можно ли настроить горячие клавиши для пользовательских команд в консоли (не в X11)? Например, на <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> поставить вызов команды `startx`.

Answer (score 3):

Да, можно, почитайте о команде `bind`

Если коротко: `bind -x'"\C-f": команда'`

Например: `bind -x'"\C-f": curl ipinfo.io/ip'` - и теперь по Ctrl+f вы увидите свой внешний IP.